# ListView being populated with same values

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-listview

I am populating a ListView with items read in from a JSONArray, being placed into a custom layout, and filling up the listView but whenever I try to run it, my ArrayList is filled with all unique values but the listView has all the same values (the first values in the ArrayList). I feel like the issue is I'm not looping through each item in the listview in my getView but I'm not sure how to do that.

> Adapter class

```
private class adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<PropertyInformationValues> data;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public adapter (Context context, ArrayList<PropertyInformationValues> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount () {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem (int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId (int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.property_result_item, null);

        TextView address = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.propertyAddress);
        TextView city = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.propertyCity);
        TextView owners = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.propertyOwner);
        TextView apn = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.propertyAPN);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
            address.setText(data.get(i).getAddress1() + " " + data.get(i).getAddress2());
            city.setText(data.get(i).getCity() + ", " + data.get(i).getState() + " " +
                    data.get(i).getZip());
            owners.setText(data.get(i).getOwner());
            apn.setText(data.get(i).getApn());
        }

        return vi;
    }
}
```

> Creating the ArrayList

```
for (int i = 0; i < propertyResults.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject row = propertyResults.getJSONObject(i);
            String address1, address2, adapterCity, adapterState, adapterZip,
                    adapterOwner, adapterApn;

            address1 = row.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
            address2 = row.getString(TAG_ADDRESS2);
            adapterCity = row.getString(TAG_CITY);
            adapterState = row.getString(TAG_STATE);
            adapterZip = row.getString(TAG_ZIP);
            adapterOwner = row.getString(TAG_OWNER);
            adapterApn = row.getString(TAG_APN);

            values.add(new PropertyInformationValues(address1, address2, adapterCity,
                    adapterState, adapterZip, adapterOwner, adapterApn));
        }

        listView.setAdapter(new adapter(this, values));
```

> property_result_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:paddingTop="20sp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/propertyAddress" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/propertyCity" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/propertyOwner" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/propertyAPN" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What logs have you collected to validate your theory? Do some base level analysis of the behavior of your application. I would started by adding logs into getView() and confirm that the views are being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi;
    if (convertView != null) {
        // view was already created, reuse what i have
        vi = convertView;
    } else {
        // no view available, create new one
        // always provide parent view, but don't attach to view hierarchy
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.property_result_item, parent, false);
    }

    // this is ineffective, google ViewHolder
    TextView address = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.propertyAddress);
    TextView city = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.propertyCity);
    TextView owners = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.propertyOwner);
    TextView apn = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.propertyAPN);

    // only retrieve data associated with currently asked position
    // don't keep calling get() all the time, that's wasteful
    PropertyInformationValues values = data.get(position);

    // assign values
    address.setText(values.getAddress1() + " " + values.getAddress2());
    city.setText(values.getCity() + ", " + values.getState() + " " + values.getZip());
    owners.setText(values.getOwner());
    apn.setText(values.getApn());

    // return loaded view
    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Um hmm, I think I see the problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
    address.setText(data.get(i).getAddress1() + " " + data.get(i).getAddress2());
    city.setText(data.get(i).getCity() + ", " + data.get(i).getState() + " " +
                                                     data.get(i).getZip());
    owners.setText(data.get(i).getOwner());
    apn.setText(data.get(i).getApn());
}
```

All this is doing is looping around and putting in all your values into the same text view over and over, likely displaying the last value in all your views.  And it does this for every view.

I generally like to do something like this.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    PhoneData phoneData = mPhoneDatas.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRosterPhone);
        holder.llPhone = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutRosterPhone);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvPhone.setText(phoneData.getNum() + " " + phoneData.getType());
    holder.llPhone.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView tvPhone;
    LinearLayout llPhone;
}
```

The problem is essentially that you attempted to loop for the listview, even though it already does it naturally.

Comment: I had just realized this right after I posted it. I basically took out the for loop  and replaced everything that had `data.get(i)` with `data.get(position)`